# How to get input file element (image)?

Tags: jquery

I have a script that converting image to base64 and I need to pass to php as json.
But I dont want to onchange function.
For example:

> onchange="uploadLogoStore(this);"<<< this is working.

But I have some condition on dropify which means I have required minimum and max height width on each data.

Right now, what i need is to get the element image document.getElementById('uploadLogostore') but I am not sure how to get it.

> uploadLogostore is a input for uploading file.

```
    $("#uploadLogostore").click(function(){
        uploadLogoStore(document.getElementById('uploadLogostore'));
    });            

   function uploadLogoStore(element) {
      var result ="";
      var file = element.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "php-ajax/upload-logostore.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"image":reader.result},
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $("#uploadLogostore").html('Uploading ...');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#uploadLogostore").html(data);

                if(data == "fail"){
                    $("#error").html('Error Uploading');
                    $("#uploadLogostore").html('Upload Image');
                }else{
                    $("#uploadLogostore").html('Done Uploading ...');
                    setTimeout(function() {                        
                    window.location.reload();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        });           

      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    }
```

Comment: What is the #uploadLogostore? Image, input, div or a link?

Comment: is a dropify input(image)

Answer (score 0):

```html
$('#uploadLogostore').change(function(){
    var file = $(this).fieldValue();
    uploadLogoStore(file[0]);
});
```